# how to show word file on php page

Tags: php, phpword

I'm using phpword library for reading word file, but phpword library first converts word file to HTML or other format files and then we have to read/access this HTML page.

But I want to display a word file content on php page without converting it to any other type of file format. Hope You understand my query.

Or Let me know if there is any other way to do this.

Here is my code

```
include_once 'Sample_Header.php';

// Read contents
$name = basename(__FILE__, '.php');
$source = __DIR__ . "/resources/{$name}.docx";

echo date('H:i:s'), " Reading contents from `{$source}`", EOL;
$phpWord = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load($source);

// Save file
echo write($phpWord, basename(__FILE__, '.php'), $writers);
```

Comment: _"But I want to display a word file content on php page without converting it to any other type of file format."_ - then your target browser(s) would have to either support displaying of that kind of document natively, or have an extension installed which enabled this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your browser can understand the type of .docx. PDF is the document type that all browsers support. We usually convert other types of document to PDF.